# Windows 10 notifications using win10toast

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I'm currently using win10toast library for notifications in my python app. Is there some way to use variables for the body of notification?

Comment: Just.. assign the variables to the function?

Answer (score 0):

f-strings should solve your problem if you want to mix predefined text with a variable in your body.

The syntax is: `f"some text {my_variable}"`. The `{my_variable}` part will be replaced by the value of `my_variable` in the string.

A full working example would be:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
my_variable = "some random text"
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Sample Notification", f"The variable I want to show contains {my_variable}")
```